# How to pass a prop to a parent component in Vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, tic-tac-toe

I am developing a Vue-Tac-Toe application just 4 fun and i am just stuck a bit now.

Please see screenshot first to understand the context.
[image: vue-tac-toe stuck in logic]

---

**Problem:** How can i pass the prop of `cellRow` to the component `Field.vue`?

**What i want:** Each Field should have a unique identification, for example the tile on the top left(first one) it should be recognized as `cellRow: 0 & cellId: 0`
because i need to have the information to simple check for a tic-tac-toe win(3 in a line etc.)

---

GameField.vue: We have a row and cell based layout.

```
<template>
  <div id="game-field">
    <div class="container">
      <template v-for="(rows, index) in 3">
        <Row :cell-row="index" />
      </template>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import Row from './Row.vue';

export default {
  components: {
    Row,
  },
  data() {
    return {};
  },
};
</script>

<style lang="scss" scoped>
.container {
    width: 400px;
    margin: 10% auto 0;
}
</style>
```

Row.Vue: Each row got 3 Fields. from 0-2.

```
<template lang="html">
  <div class="row">
    <Field
      v-for="(fieldId, index) in 3"
      :key="fieldId"
      :cell-id="index"
    />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import Field from './Field.vue';

export default {
  components: {
    Field,
  },
  props: {
    cellRow: {
      type: Number,
      default: 0,
    },
  },
  data() {
    return {

    };
  },
};
</script>

<style lang="scss" scoped>
</style>
```

Field.vue:

```
<template lang="html">
  <div class="cell">
    <slot />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  props: {
    cellId: {
      type: Number,
      default: 0,
    },
  },
  data() {
    return {};
  },
};
</script>

<style lang="scss" scoped>
  .cell {
    margin: 1px 3px -3px -1px;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: white;
    display: inline-block;
    cursor: pointer;
  }
</style>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand the question correctly, you can pass `cellRow` prop of `Row` component further simply as a prop of `Field` component.

**Row** (pass `cellRow` as a prop to `Field`)

```
<template lang="html">
  <div class="row">
    <Field
      v-for="(fieldId, index) in 3"
      :key="fieldId"
      :cell-id="index"
      :row-id="cellRow" // passing row index to Field component
    />
  </div>
</template>
...
```

**Field**

```
...
<script>
export default {
  props: {
    cellId: {
      type: Number,
      default: 0,
    },
    rowId: {  // defining new prop type
      type: Number,
      default: 0,
    },
  },
  ...
};
</script>
```

Here is a little demo:

```js
Vue.config.devtools = false;
Vue.config.productionTip = false;


Vue.component('Row', {
  template:
    `
<div class="row">
  <Field
    v-for="(fieldId, index) in 3"
    :key="fieldId"
    :cell-id="index"
    :row-id="cellRow"
  />
</div>
`,
  props: {
    cellRow: {
      type: Number,
      default: 0
    }
  }
})

Vue.component('Field', {
  template:
    `
  <div class="cell">
    <p>Row Id: {{ rowId }}</p>
    <p>Cell Id: {{ cellId }}</p>
  </div>
`,
  props: {
    cellId: {
      type: Number,
      default: 0
    },
    rowId: {
      type: Number,
      default: 0
    }
  }
})

new Vue({
  el: '#demo',
  template:
    `
<div id="game-field">
    <div class="container">
      <template v-for="(rows, index) in 3">
        <Row :cell-row="index" />
      </template>
    </div>
  </div>
`
})
```

```css
.cell {
  margin: 1px 3px 3px 1px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: gray;
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: white;
  padding: 5px;
}
.container {
    width: 400px;
    margin: 10% auto 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="demo"></div>
```

Comment: Are you not setting the prop new with this way? i need the value of row to be inside the Field.vue component. it needs to be related.

Comment: In this way new prop is created on a `Field` instance but the same value of a row index is being passed. Relations are preserved. I have updated the answer by adding a small demo, I hope it helps.